# HTML code not working in chrome via powershell

Tags: html, powershell, google-chrome

I am trying to open an html code using chrome via powershell and it gives me the following error:

```
This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in size.html.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

This was working just until 2 days ago and I do not remember changing any settings in the past 2 days.

I am using the command `Start chrome filename.html` for this.
If I use the command `Start firefox filename.html`, the file is opening which means there is no typo in the html file.

At the same time I am able to open the same file using chrome if I use the GUI and double click which means chrome can read the html file.

There are clearly ways to open the html for me but I am eager to know why chrome is not able to read the html file when using powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I think chrome interprets it as url (other than firefox). Therefore, you need the `file:///` prefix to specify that it's a file path. But then, relative paths won't work, so you need to use the full path:

`start chrome file:///c:/your-path.../filename.html`

You can also let PowerShell resolve the full path for you:

`start chrome ("file:///" + (Resolve-Path filename.html))`

Comment: Yes. It does work with the whole path. But I'm already in the folder so i shouldn't need to use the whole path ...right? What bothers me is that the command "Start chrome filename.html" was working fine ...until it just stopped.

Comment: @Abhi The important part is the `file:///` prefix, so chrome knows you are not opening a domain or url, but a file path. BUT if you do that, you have to specifiy the full path. See my edit, maybe that makes it a little easier.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense.Thank you :)

Comment: @Abhi Ur welcome. If an answer was helpful, consider upvoting or accepting it.

Comment: This is a new account so it says i dont have enough reputation to upvote. But it says my feedback has been recorded.